# What as="script" in <link> tag does

Tags: javascript, html, performance

Facebook is loading some scripts with the link tag, e.g.:

```
<link 
  rel="preload" 
  href="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/9qpVu0vr8kA.js" 
  as="script" 
  crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Using `as="script"`.

What is this strategy doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content):

> Using `as` to specify the type of content to be preloaded allows the
>   browser to:
>
> - Prioritize resource loading more accurately.
> - Match future requests, reusing the same resource if appropriate.
> - Apply the correct content security policy to the resource.
> - Set the correct Accept request headers for it.